Not able to remove nested array element in array
In the below the screen shot , mentioned nested element as child array.

I wanted to remove child array element , I used below the script but it's only remove first element.
removeChildWidget(parIndex:number,index:number){
    if (parIndex >= 0) {
       const widgetNumber = this.dashRightWidget[parIndex]?.widgetNumber;
       const widgeDashtNumber = this.dashboardWidgets[parIndex]?.widgetNumber;

       this.widgets.forEach((widget) => {
        if (widget.widgetNumber == widgeDashtNumber) {

          console.log("wid",widget.child[index])
          if (index >= 0) widget.child.splice(index, 1)
         console.log("wid",widget)
        }
      });
      console.log('final output', this.dashboardWidgets)
  
    }    
  }


please share all the console.log message as well as some sample input data showing the issue happening. If possible a stackblitz, do you want to empty the array?

The problem is in the forEach loop. When you are iterating through the widgets array and check condition (widget.widgetNumber == widgeDashtNumber) it only matches one widget and when you use splice() it is called based on the first matching element. This results in only the first match being modified.
To remove all child array elements you need to iterate over all items in the this.widgets array check each parent and remove the child if the condition is met.
Refer the code below for more reference:


removeChildWidget(parIndex: number, index: number) {
  if (parIndex >= 0) {
    const widgeDashtNumber = this.dashboardWidgets[parIndex] ? .widgetNumber;

    this.widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      if (widget.widgetNumber === widgeDashtNumber && widget.child && index >= 0) {
        widget.child.splice(index, 1); // Remove all children at the specified index if the widget.child exists
      }
    });

    console.log('Updated widgets:', this.widgets);
    console.log('Final output:', this.dashboardWidgets);
  }
}



Note: This is based on the minimum facts provided. Appreciate it if you could provide the actual

In general you should avoid remove elements using javaScript. Make it in .html
Really I don't know about your code, but if you have a @for iterate over an array and only you need change the array
@for (element in filteredArray;track $index)
{
    @for (child in filteredArray.childs;track $index)
    {
        <your-child>
    }
}

And
removeChildWidget(parIndex,index)
{
     filteredArray[parIndex].child.splice(index,1);
     filteredArray[parIndex].child=[...filteredArray[parIndex].child]
}

